# Product of Random Adjacency Matrices Based on an Underlying Fixed Graph

Tags: matrices, random, random-graphs

Consider the adjacency matrix $$A$$ of a fixed undirected graph. So the $i,j$ element of $A$ is 1 if node $i$ is connected to node $j$ and it is zero, else. Define a random graph by deleting each edge of the original graph, independently with probability $p$. Define the adjacency matrix of such a random graph by $B$. Let $B(k)$ be independent copies of this random adjacency matrix. What can we say about the product $P(n)=B(1) B(2)...B(n)$ and how it scales with $n$. I expect this is known, but was not able to find anything in the literature. For example, can be quantify $(1/n)\log(||P(n)||)$ for an appropriate matrix norm?

Comment: Doesn't this model become rather degenerate as $n$ scales? Without self-loops, with probability $p^{\vert E\vert}$, $B(k)=0$ as we delete every edge. Therefore, the probability $P(n)\neq 0$ is at most $(1-p^{\vert E\vert})^n\leq \exp(-np^{\vert E\vert})$ so tends to $0$ exponentially fast.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, you are right. I should have asked it with self-loops. So what would happen if we replaced the $B(k)$ with $B(k)+I$?